# Sitecore Mapping from Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, sitecore, dynamic-data-exchange

I have a sample XML:

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="contact">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="contactid" />
    <attribute name="contactid" />
    <attribute name="lastname" />
    <order attribute="fullname" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="lastname" operator="not-null" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="btable2" from="id1" to="id2" visible="false" link- 
      type="outer" alias="a_0151c8f511fd">
      <attribute name="totalnumberofproductregistrations" />
      <attribute name="fiscalyear" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

How can I access the totalnumberofproductregistrations? I can't access this since it says that its not part of the current entity set up. Anyone encountered this before?

Sitecore Mapping from Dynamics CRM through Data Exchange Framework

Not mapping. Not getting any value which has value from CRM

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194817/discussion-on-question-by-jdmentolaroc-sitecore-mapping-from-dynamics-crm).